# Has anyone used ArcGIS for 'automatically' detecting lineaments from a high-resolution (1m) DEM?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, dem, network-analyst, lidar, subsurface

I have a set of DEM's produced from LIDAR data. I am wondering if anyone is familiar with or knew of any published research papers which looked at (semi-)automatically detecting lineaments /or fractures of the Earth surface. I would like to do this in ArcGIS 10.1.
Or is there any way to write an application/code in ArcGIS for it?

Comment: You say "fractures of the earth surface" is this the same as a fault (note I am not a geologist)? Well quick Google search using the search terms (lidar geological faults)  threw up [this](https://cloud.sdsc.edu/v1/AUTH_opentopography/www/education/Arrowsmith_Frankel_lidar_3.pdf) document.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with groundwater potentiality? I quick search (of peer-reviewed article database) brought some up I could share with you.

Comment: This question is very broad, imo. I searched in the Web of Science database the words: 'LiDAR' and 'lineaments'; there were some results: [1](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=5&SID=1A4miOlFyItt29Lal8i&page=1&doc=1),[2](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=5&SID=1A4miOlFyItt29Lal8i&page=1&doc=5),[3](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=5&SID=1A4miOlFyItt29Lal8i&page=1&doc=7). Adding the word 'automatic', it came out the following article...

Comment: http://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=6&SID=1A4miOlFyItt29Lal8i&page=1&doc=1. However, the question is broad both in the sense of asking researches and documents about this task; but also in sense of writing an entire application to perform such analysis.